# Syncing a branch with master

Tags: git

I have two branches

Master branch:  A -> B -> C -> D

lag-branch   :  A -> X -> Y

Note that patches X and Y add new files and are not in conflict with
files in the master branch.

I want the following sync'd lag-branch : A-> X -> Y -> B -> C -> D

But, when I run this command:

git merge -s recursive -X theirs master

I get merge conflicts between files that I haven't touched.
For example, the unmerged paths are of type "deleted by us".

Is it possible to merge master into lag (i.e. sync lag-branch with master) without
actually having to manually resolve conflicts or deal with "deleted by
us/them unmerged paths

Comment: Conflicts would possibly be unavoidable depending on which files you've updated, but just try a simple merge on top i.e. `git merge master`

Comment: Usually you'd want to rebase master onto your feature branches for easy fast forward merges back to master without kinky merge commits cluttering your tree. `git checkout lag-branch && git rebase master`

Comment: Agree with Jeff. What you show a,x,y,b,c,d wont happen with a merge since merging produces a merge commit. The way you show it, you could get a branch with A->X->Y->B'->C'->D'. Note the primes because they will have different commit IDs even if their contents are the same.

Comment: @RobbieAverill I only work on master branch, I don't touch the lag-branch. Is there a way to just resolve all conflicts by using masters version?

Comment: Why dont you just checkout master and do a regular (recursive) merge of lag-branch. What happens if you try that? "git checkout master && git merge lag-branch"

Comment: @DavidN I want to sync lag-branch with master, not the other way around. When I do git checkout lag-branch && git rebase master, I get merge conflicts that cannot be auto resolved

Comment: ah, sorry, got that the wrong way. Have you googled for ""deleted by us" unmerged paths git"